# WordPress Slider Revolution Image does not show up on Laptop

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, revolution-slider

I have a page that uses the slider revolution.  It displays perfectly on a desktop, however, on laptops, the images doesn't load for some random reason.  I have been trying different solutions from google but none of them seem to work.  I have tried to set other images and it seems to work but just not this particular image :(

----Edit ---

Screen shots

[image]

Monitor: http://www.lg.com/uk/monitors/lg-29EA93

[image]

Resolution : 2560-by-1600 native resolution at 227 pixels per inch 
http://www.apple.com/ca/macbook-pro/specs/

Thoughts?

https://720sweets.com/homepage-b/

Comment: What do you mean "on laptops" - like multiple laptops? Any consistent difference between browser & os on machines that it works on vs ones that it doesn't? A laptop isn't a special computer or anything, just generally a lower resolution than a desktop, so it would be weird if it doesn't work on all laptops.

Comment: I am viewing the slider on my laptop and it works just fine.  Maybe it's just chosen me.

Comment: My apology for not being clear, I added extra details to be more clear!~